# Detect Event When the model is created dynamically in emberjs

Tags: javascript, templates, model, ember.js, javascriptmvc

I have created some model App.Markets
In here I am going to display "hello world".

```
App.DashboardController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    test: function(){
    var post = App.Markets.createRecord({
       name: "NAME123",
       created: "CREATED123"
    });
    post.one('didCreate', function() {
      console.log("hello world");
    });
    post.save();
}
```

But I cannot see this message when I create a new record in App.Markets Model.

Comment: did it work out? let me know if it helped so I can improve further my answer if not

Answer (score 1):

The `didCreate` hook is triggered when adapter has gotten confirmation from your API that the record was saved. If you cannot see this message it's probably because there was an error calling your API.

To see what is going on, setting the model's `stateManager.enableLogging` property to true. With this in place you will be able to see console.log messages as the model transitions between states

```
App.DashboardController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    test: function(){
    var post = App.Markets.createRecord({
       name: "NAME123",
       created: "CREATED123",
       "stateManager.enableLogging": true
    });
    post.one('didCreate', function() {
      console.log("hello world");
    });
    post.save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your application setup looks like, but have a look at this simple [demo](http://jsbin.com/ibakod/10/edit) that uses the `FixtureAdapter` for simplicity reasons who show's that it's working.

Let me know if it helps.